# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' error shows after importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have install tensor flow using this python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl for python 3.8 in windows 10.

After running import tensorflow as tf it shows me traceback error and I am not able to use tensorflow ?
I have also installed CUDA 10.2 driver too.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python38/Scripts/ArtificalNeuralNetwork/ANN.py", line 3, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

A very common reason for this error being thrown is not having vs C++ redistributables dowloaded.

Download here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads