# Tensorflow installation on Windows: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I ran through the TensorFlow object detection installation on Windows.

https://medium.com/riow/tensorflow-object-detection-on-windows-ad10bfde217c

After successfully installing TensorFlow object detection,

I ran  following command to test, and receiving error below. How can this be fixed?

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing *pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in 
> from object_detection.builders import model_builder
> File "c:\testimage\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 23, in 
> from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
> File "c:\testimage\models\research\object_detection\builders\anchor_generator_builder.py", line 23, in 
> from object_detection.anchor_generators import flexible_grid_anchor_generator
> File "c:\testimage\models\research\object_detection\anchor_generators\flexible_grid_anchor_generator.py", line 17, in 
> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init**.py", line 41, in 
> from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 40, in 
> from tensorflow.python.eager import context
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
> raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\TestImage\models\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Currently using Python 3.8 with latest tensorflow, with tensorflow-cpu

Comment: Idk. I do seem to have both a `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py` file and a `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py`. Best I can tell, your error is coming from the first, while looking for the second? It also looks like one or both of these are generated from something called SWIG, which I guess generates python interfaces to C/C++ classes? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342220/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal-error-shows-a?rq=1) looks relevant.

Comment: Maybe your tensorflow didn't install correctly. Did  you get any errors there? [This also looks relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165561/import-tensorflow-error-in-windows-server-2016-dll-load-failed-importing-pywra?rq=1)

Comment: Again, to link to link back to the tensorflow install instructions, [there is listed a requirement there for the visual C++ redistributable](https://www.tensorflow.org/install), which based on the above two SO posts sounds related. Could that be it?

Comment: interesting, yeah, I already installed the C++ package, so not sure, I will keep looking

Comment: Here's another stab in the dark: if you installed TF w/o the C++ package and then reinstalled TF, or if you installed the C++ package afterwards, it wouldn't surprise me if TF needs that C++ package at TF install time (based on a glance at the missing module) so that it can generate the module then, for whatever that speculation is worth...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tldr;

You need to install the C++ redistributable mentioned [on the install page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) *before installing TensorFlow* so that TensorFlow can  use it to generate code at install time.

#### Details:

I'm not an expert but it sounds like this was key:

The `pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py` module you are missing appears to me to be a SWIG-generated python interface to a C++ library, or something of that nature. My guess is, that file gets generated when you install TensorFlow (it reminds me of how some Ruby gems have to compile C++ when you install them, for whatever that's worth). Since you don't have that generated file, my guess is that the C++ package mentioned on the TensorFlow install page is needed for that code generation, so you need to have the C++ package installed *before* installing TensorFlow.

Totally a guess, but perhaps you installed the C++ package after TF. In that case, you should be able to uninstall TF, install the C++ package, and then install TF again.

Maybe a lingering question is if there were any indicative error messages on installing TF about the missing C++ package and if not, maybe there should be.